# How do I specify what the column type a DataGridView chooses to use when using DataTable as its DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a column in my `DataGridView` that is a custom type to display values of `MyObjectType`.  My `DataTable` has the column created as `MyObjectType`, but the `DataGridView` creates a `DataGridViewTextBox` column and populates it with `MyObjectType.ToString()`; which is not the behavior I want.   I need to display both an image and a text value for the `MyObjectType` value in a single column; similar to how the name column in explorer when using details view so I can't shoehorn the data into a single column like the default behavior.

Can I either force the data to be loaded into preexisting columns; or is there a away to specify that a `MyObjectTypeColumn` should be created to display `MyObjectType` data?

Comment: It would be worth updating your question with the information you added as a comment to my answer (which I've now deleted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `AutogenerateColumns` property to false allowed me to use columns with types that I defined.  Am I blind though, or is that property not exposed in the designer grid.

Comment: It's not a part of the Properties that I can tell for the DataGridView. Not all Properties are exposed however.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to create a custom DataGridView Column.

http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0707061&page=1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx

Comment: I have created it, but when I set a Datatable for a source it creates a text column for the MyObjectType and only shows its ToString value instead of creating a MyObjectTypeColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your DisplayMember and ValueMember if you are binding, I believe. I had a similar problem when binding to a ComboBox and I was just getting String[] array as well.